# Sharing data between Python and R in Pycharm

Tags: python, r, pycharm

I have been using Pycharm for Python for some time, and it is a very descent IDE.
However, it can also manage R very well.
Hence, the question: if you create a dataframe with Python, is there a way to make that dataframe accessible to R code in Pycharm without saving the file on the machine as .csv or other forms?
Note that codes for Python and R are stored in different files but within the same project (.py file and .r file).

Comment: Is `Apache Arrow` useful for you ? <https://arrow.apache.org/> <https://www.dremio.com/apache-arrow-explained/>

Comment: Thanks @IronHandOdin I am now using pd.to_excel and readxl::read_excel to solve this issue. I found using excel files a bit more rrliable and generating less errors than Arrow (feather), but you might have a different experience?